# Как создать динамический Layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Возможно ли и как создавать динамические(горизонтальные) Layout-ы? Возможно ли подобным способом способу создания других динамичных компонентов(код ниже)?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    Button btn;
    LinearLayout lnr;
    EditText editText;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        lnr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.amain);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(MainActivity.this);
                Button btn_delete = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                btn_delete.setText("Удалить");
                lnr.addView(textView, lparams);
                lnr.addView(checkBox, lparams);
                lnr.addView(btn_delete, lparams);
```

Comment: Код вы написали, осталось его запустить и узнаете, возможно или нет. В чём конкретный вопрос/проблема?

Comment: Я создал динамическое добавление отдельных компонентов, которые не связаны между собой. Как создать все эти 3 компоненты, но что бы они были связаны между собой и были как единый блок. Ну или другими словами, как создать динамичный новый Layout, в котором будут три компонента

Comment: Вы уже поместили эти три компонента в один LinearLayout методом `addView`. Теперь этот LinearLayout и является единым блоком. Как ещё вы хотите чтобы они были связаны? Или вы хотите LinearLayout тоже программно создать и заполнить?

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Я хочу создавать программно и заполнять Layout. Как это сделать? За аналогией как-то?